# Heroku - How to avoid memory_limit issue in cron scheduler

Tags: laravel, heroku, scheduler

We have two dynos

One running for web and another for scheduler.

```
 web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf public/
 sheduler: php artisan schedule:daemon
```

There are 4 different cron tasks and all working fine.
But one of them is heavy weight and it need higher memory_limit.

But not sure how can we increase the memory_limit against that scheduler dyno only ?
The same issue was there in web too but can able to override the issue with fpm_custom.conf.

I tried below method in Procfile

```
sheduler: php -d memory_limit=1024M artisan schedule:daemon
```

But seems to not helped.
So any help how we can override the issue ?

Comment: create queues and call them from your cron job.

Comment: @jpk would you mind sharing any updates on this one?

Comment: @Daniel we have created new Dyno 'worker' to manage that individual task.